# Finding largest number in recursion function

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm trying to find the largest number in a hailstone sequence, yet I'm fairly new to recursion. This code works for some numbers, but for numbers like 27 or 678 it freezes, and I've spent many hours attempting to figure out why.

```
int next(int n)
{
  if(n != 1)
  {
    if(n % 2 == 0)
    {
      return n/2;
    }
    else
    {
      return (n*3)+1;
    }
  }
  return n;
}
int haillargest(int begin)
{
  int nhail = next(begin);
  if(begin == 1)
  {
    return begin;
  }
  else if(haillargest(nhail) > begin)
  {
    return haillargest(nhail);
  }
  else
  {
   return begin;
  }
}
```

Am I using recursion wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Quick performance tip: *don't call `haillargest` twice with the same argument.* Store the value in a local variable!

Comment: To add on to what Angew said. The official word for that is ["memoization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

Comment: @ AndyG: Not quite.  Memoization is when you keep all useful results and then look up the one you need from a previous call.  Keeping a local variable is merely an optimization, albeit a good one..

Comment: Do remember to choose a favourite answer; this allows SO to retire the question.  More important, follow the link @NathanOliver supplied.  Learning how to debug, even with only **print** statements, is an important skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fumbled the check and return value in **haillargest**.  It went away when I cleaned up the presentation a bit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int next(int n)
{
  if(n == 1) return n;
  if(n % 2 == 0) return n/2;
  return (n*3)+1;
}

int haillargest(int begin)
{
  static nest = 0;
  int nhail = next(begin);
  int result, new_num;

//  printf("Enter %d %d %d\n", nest++, begin, nhail);

  if (begin == 1)
    result = 1;
  else {
    new_num = haillargest(nhail);
    if (new_num > begin)
      result = new_num;
    else
      result = begin;
  }

//  printf("Leave %d %d\n", --nest, result);
  return result;
}

main() {
printf("%d %d\n",  27, haillargest(27));
printf("%d %d\n", 678, haillargest(678));
}
```

Output:

```
27 9232
678 4372
```

Comment: "static nest"? did you mean "static int nest"?

Comment: Yes, that would be cleaner.  It should be commented out, as that was simply part of my tracing code.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, I understand the issue and what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the current "largestSoFar" number into the next iteration of the function and compare it to the next number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int hailstone(const int n) {
    return n % 2 ? 3 * n + 1 : n / 2;
}

int largest(const int n, int largestSoFar = 0) {
    int h = hailstone(n);
    if (h > largestSoFar)
        largestSoFar = h;
    if (h == 1)
        return largestSoFar;
    return largest(h, largestSoFar);
}

int main() {
    int l = largest(7);
    std::cout << l << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but returning it as the functional value is a more compact use of recursion.